# Xamarin .jar binding - 'Bitmap could not be found'

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a `.jar` file with a Java interface called `MyService`, which has a method:

```
boolean printBitmapObject(android.graphics.Bitmap bitmap, byte[] result);
```

I would like to use this `.jar` file in C# in my Android Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2015. I did following steps:

1. I created a new library binding project.
2. I put the `.jar` file into `Jars` directory of the new project with `BuildAction` property set to `InputJar`.
3. The project was built successfully.
4. I added reference to the library binding project into my main project.

Unfortunately, I cannot build my main project anymore, because there is an error in the auto-generated C# code:

```
    public interface IMyService : global::Android.OS.IInterface
    {
       bool PrintBitmapObject (Bitmap bmp, byte[] result); //"Bitmap" is red underlined
    }
```

with message `"The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"`.

There is also an auto-generated abstract class `IMyServiceStub`, which also doesn't recognize `Bitmap`. Moreover, it doesn't know some auto-generated `BitmapStub` either:

```
public abstract class IMyServiceStub : global::Android.OS.Binder, global::Android.OS.IInterface, IMyService
{
    ...
    protected override bool OnTransact (int code, global::Android.OS.Parcel data, global::Android.OS.Parcel reply, int flags)
    {
        ...
        case TransactionPrintBitmapObject: {
                data.EnforceInterface (descriptor);
                Bitmap arg0 = default (Bitmap); //Bitmap red underlined
                arg0 = BitmapStub.AsInterface (data.ReadStrongBinder ()); //BitmapStub red underlined
                byte [] arg1 = default (byte []);
                var result = this.PrintBitmapObject (arg0, arg1);
                reply.WriteNoException ();
                reply.WriteInt (result ? 1 : 0);
                data.WriteByteArray (arg1);
                return true;
                }
        ...
    }

}
```

I tried adding `using Bitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap` to the auto-generated file, but it doesn't help, because `BitmapStub` remains unknown and my changes are overwritten during the next build.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? Or is it a known bug in Xamarin (I use version 4.0)?

Comment: Can you share the .jar so i can try to help you?

Comment: @jzeferino I cannot, unfortunately, I would break NDA...

Answer (score 2):

Jar binding will not work with Android Library Projects, you need to include `.aar` file. Jar files do not reference android specific libraries in jar, but `.aar` file correctly references all required android related libraries.

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting... Could you please add some details? I have this third party jar file that works great in my Android app written in Java and built in the Android Studio. However, I have no aar file. How can I get it? What steps should I follow in order to be able to use the jar file functionality from my c# Xamarin Android app in Visual Studio?

Comment: You will find aar file in `build\outputs\aar` folder. Please follow this, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/

Comment: The linked manual explains how to bind an .aar file. However, I don't have any .aar file and I don't have the source code for the jar file, so I cannot build it by myself. My jar file is a third-party library. Can I convert the jar into an aar somehow?

Comment: No you can't convert `.jar` to `.aar` file. You need to contact library provider and tell them to give you `.aar` file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played in Xamarin in a while, however the Android.Graphics.Bitmap namespace belongs to the Java language, not c#. So the generated c# code would not know anything about that namespace.

Therefore, I would try adding `using System.Drawing;` instead of `using Bitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap`

You may also have to manually add that DLL as a reference to the C# project if the compiler does not recognize the *System.Drawing* namespace.

Let me know how that works out.

Comment: This is not a solution, unfortunately. Even if I add `using System.Drawing;`, it is overwritten by the next build. The file is auto-generated.

Comment: Yes I'm aware... but since the error is generated at build time, its looking for the windows type, not the Java type (unless Visual Studio is compiling Java source and not just generating it, which would be news to me).